# How to reverse image of a rectangle in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application and a rectangle inside it and I use rectangle.setFill() for filling the rectangle with an image. I want to know how I can reverse the image of my rectangle. ( I want to reverse it both vertically and horizontally and their combinations.)

Let's say the image I put on my rectangle is blue and has a red circle on the upper right part. I want to have images with the red circle being located in the lower right, lower left, and upper left side of the rectangle.

I have found some solutions with Canvas and GraphicsContext but it seems they are not applicable to Rectangle. Any solutions for Rectangle?

Also, I have put my rectangle in an anchorpane, if it's important to know.

Comment: what do you mean by "reverse"?

Comment: I will edit my question so that it becomes clear.

Comment: ahh - I see: you want to apply some kind of transform?

Comment: Not necessarily transform. Any solutions that work are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is probably to transform the node, rather than trying to flip the image itself. Two benefits of that are:

1. JavaFX provides easy ways to transform (translate, rotate, scale, etc.) nodes, and
2. You can use a single `Image` for all nodes.

The simplest transform to use in this case, as pointed out by @mipa, is scaling. To flip the node horizontally use `node.setScaleX(-1)`. To flip the node vertically use `node.setScaleY(-1)`.

Here's an example showing all four of your desired orientations:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    double width = 250;
    double height = 250;

    Image image = new Image(/* your image URL */, width, height, true, true);
    ImagePattern fill = new ImagePattern(image);

    Rectangle normal = new Rectangle(width, height, fill);
    Rectangle horizontal = new Rectangle(width, height, fill);
    Rectangle vertical = new Rectangle(width, height, fill);
    Rectangle both = new Rectangle(width, height, fill);

    flipNode(horizontal, true, false);
    flipNode(vertical, false, true);
    flipNode(both, true, true);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.add(normal, 0, 0);
    grid.add(horizontal, 1, 0);
    grid.add(vertical, 0, 1);
    grid.add(both, 1, 1);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void flipNode(Node node, boolean horiztonally, boolean vertically) {
    node.setScaleX(horiztonally ? -1 : 1);
    node.setScaleY(vertically ? -1 : 1);
  }
}
```

The other transform you could use is rotation, but the above is easier.

Comment: If you want to mirror it you can also set the scale to -1.0

Comment: Interesting. I would not have thought of that. I'll update my answer as that's much simpler.